# Search for text contained in a text file and remove them from another text file in java

Tags: java

I have a text file that was output from a java program that finds the frequency of people's names mentioned in multiple documents and writes them to a file (peopleNames.txt) like this:

```
article1location\article1 name1:countofname1# name2:countofname2# name3:countofname3# ...
article2location\article2 name1:countofname1# name2:countofname2# name3:countofname3# ...
article3location\article3 name1:countofname1# name2:countofname2# name3:countofname3# ...
```

the names correspond to people names identified in each article along with the frequency they appear in the article, there are about 90,000 articles. I have another text file (titles.lst) that contains a list of about 40 different titles and their abbreviations (such as Mr., Mrs., President, Sir etc.) I would like to use this list in the file to search for and remove these titles from peopleNames.txt. I am not sure how to go about it in java as I am new to java and need to modify the original code in java that produced peopleNames.txt to accommodate title removal.

My program is identifying a person such as Mr John Smith as different from John Smith, so removing the titles would give me a more accurate count of the names mentioned in the articles.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: As you're probably aware, if an article refers to someone by their full name (perhaps with title) at the start, it'll probably begin to refer to them only by surname for the rest. As a result, your list might be a bit larger than it should be. Handling that requires a more substantial rewrite, unfortunately.

Comment: You should probably include an example of a line from titles.lst, as it might help people come up with the best solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can use regular expressions to remove all instances:
public class Test {

```
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
        String s = "Mr Tom and Ms Jane";
        s = s.replaceAll("\\bMr\\b|\\bMs\\b", "");
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

For the sake of explaining the comments:

```
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
        String [] titles = args;
        String regex = "\\b"+titles[0]+"\\b";
        for (int i=1; i<titles.length; i++) {
            regex += "|\\b" + titles[i] + "\\b";
        }

        String s = "Mr Tom and Ms Jane";
        s = s.replaceAll(regex, "");
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

You can also use the replace option repeatedly rather than building a regular expression. I don't actually know which is quicker. I would hazard a guess that it depends on the java implementation.

```
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
        String [] titles = args;
        String s = "Mr Tom and Ms Jane";
        for (int i=1; i<titles.length; i++) {
            s = s.replaceAll("\\b"+titles[0]+"\\b", "");
        }
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

Comment: But, how would you know all the possible titles a person has? President, Mr, Mrs, Sir, Don, King,... It's easier to find the first space and split it.

Comment: @AsierAranbarri in the same way as you would find out that `words[0]` is `Mr, Mrs, Sir, Don, King` and not `Potato`

Comment: As I said, you split it. Then you CHECK if it's in the list. If you do it your way, you have to MANUALLY alter the code each time a new title appears. If you split the first space and then make a method to check if the word is in that list, you don't need to change your code.

Comment: @AsierAranbarri it is obvious that this code is not for production but it gives good idea how to implement it. Titles have to be read from the file `titles.lst` then build the String passed as regex to `replaceAll`-> `s.replaceAll(buildTitlesRegEx("titles.lst"), "");`

Comment: Isn't it easier (without regex, regular expressions, ...) to just :
1. Split the first word.
2. Check if that word is a title.

Comment: Splitting words on a space doesn't work as I've commented more than once. Some titles contain spaces just as some names contain spaces. Thus your technique will be unable to deal with them. Simple yes, reliable no.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would do:
1. Parse the titles.lst document and put every title in a Set
2. Parse peopleNames.txt, and for every line check if the name is in the Title's Set
3. If it is, remove it.
4. Check for double entry, since Mr. John Smith and John Smith will now be the same.